# What's the difference between 为 and 来？

Tags: meaning, difference

Sometimes i see them in the same position . I think they both mean "for".. Please explain to me .. For example: 结力量来捍卫和平 ; 每到换李或者节假日的时候，各大商场都会举办一些活动来吸引顾客。

Comment: Questions like these are much easier to answer if you provide an example or two!

Comment: 举办一些活动来吸引顾客 and 为吸引顾客而举办一些活动。

Answer (score 1):

举办一些活动来吸引顾客 and 为吸引顾客而举办一些活动， are two different sentence structures, but the same meaning.

In 举办一些活动来吸引顾客, **来** can be translated as "to do", which means "for the purpose of".

举办一些活动来吸引顾客。= They have promotions **to attract** customers.

In 为吸引顾客而举办一些活动, **为** directly indicates the purpose of doing something.

为吸引顾客而举办一些活动。 = **For the purpose of** attracting more customers, they will have promotions today.

Yes, they both mean "for the purpose".

为。。。而。。。is a very useful sentence structure. For example,

爸爸为了养家而做两份工作。= My father works two jobs to support our family.

Comment: Well done. A good lesson.

Comment: @PdotWang So, for expression" for the purpose of" , 为 and 来 have the same meanings , yes?

Comment: 为 directly means "for the purpose of", but 来 is indirect. The basic meaning of 来 is to come, but it has other meanings. For example, 我来清理垃圾 = I am willing to clean up the trash.